# Entering cmd in windows 10 file explorer nothing happens

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I remember several weeks ago, I was able to open a command prompt from Windows File Explorer by entering CMD in the address bar of the file explorer window.

Now, it is not working, and it works only if I run from the windows search or the run window.

Any idea how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

## Troubleshooting and notes:

- I ensured cmd.exe is in the system environment path c:\windows\system32
- I can open cmd from the search and from the run box.
- My machine is under a corporate policy but everyone else can open cmd from the file explorer window

## Update:

- I noticed when I start the laptop, and before all the background services start, I can enter CMD in the file explorer address bar, and it works. But, after everything is settled down, it stops working. I am thinking maybe after VPN starts or after the policies are updated.
- I am able to enter `%comspec%` in the address bar, and it works.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `SET` command (run from Command Prompt)?

Comment: This works for me. What happens when you run `cmd`?

Comment: Interesting! It works on this PC, though I'd not tried it before. If it no longer works, look to recent changes -- Windows update? GPO edits (if it is a corporate machine, I'd understand why IT would lock down that feature)? If your own PC, try SFC and DISM to fix issues.

Comment: Works fine here.  Try a different Windows User Profile (Account)

Comment: I'll try the suggestions above, however, when I enter cmd from the address bar, nothing happens. It works fine with all the other methods.

Comment: @w32sh I can't post the output of `SET` here. Can you ask me a more specific question? See the update on the question above for details about what I did for troubleshooting.

Comment: It will be a PITA but you can always use the process monitor (sysinternals) to trace what it happening.  Narrowing down your filters will be difficult but do-able.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas can you please give me more leads so that I can look them up? I have this process monitor but not sure how to use it to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Filter on "process is explorer.exe".  Then play.. try "result != SUCCESS".. try path contains CMD.. and so on until you get a hit that means something.

Comment: Great, will give it a try. I thought you were referring to process explorer. I tried to download the process monitor, but it is blocked. Can I do the same using process explorer?